# Change Shipping Method based on weight and destination

Tags: checkout, shipping

I couldn't find a good solid answer for my scenario so forgive me if this has been asked. (I googled and checked the suggested questions when asking)

Anyways, I have a client that wants anything over 10 ounces to be USPS Priority Mail, and any international order to only show USPS Priority Mail International. All the options are highlighted in the back end and I am kind of stumped as this doesn't seem like an issue I was really hired to deal with...

Regardless, is there some way I can use table rate shipping or something so that I can do something similar to this psuedo code:

```
if weight greater than 10 ounces
shipping method = USPS Priority

if destination NOT in US
shipping method = USPS Priority International
```

To be honest, I don't even know the difference between shipping methods. (Who physically mails things nowadays? :P ) But, that's what the client wants, can anyone point me in the direction of accomplishing this?

Much thanks in advance! :)

EDIT: On some larger orders, USPS doesn't even show up as an option during checkout. Is it because of weight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I cannot add comment can you check the following links
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032884/magento-two-flat-rate-shipping-rates-based-on-weight
or there is a free extension by Webshopapps Matrix Rates
https://sites.google.com/a/webshopapps.com/webshopapps-wiki/extensions/matrix-rates 
I think this will solve your issue .

Comment: That seems like I can just change the rate of shipping for each criteria and not the method. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: This is a long time after the question. But since I'm done with the client, this turned out to be the best course of action for anyone else needing an answer. Kudos!

Comment: Hey @Vales glad that link helped. Cheers!

Comment: @Roney Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps matrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps matrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate.

Comment: @Roney can you help me regard Matrix rate https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/241323/39050

Comment: Anyone knows how to give free shipping using Webshopapps  Matrix Rates in SHopping Cart Pricing rule?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using live rates (via USPS directly), as opposed to defining your own rates then a custom carrier like Matrixrates will not work, as its purely for defining your own custom based rates.

In this scenario you would have needed to add code into USPS to prevent shipping when weight > limit and destination is US. The international shipping will show by itself, no change needed there.

There are various weight limits for each carrier, and on each shipping method. Further details here:

https://www.usps.com/ship/compare-domestic-services.htm