# How to apply Shipping Restriction to particular products - WebShop Matrix Rate Shipping Extension?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, custom-options, third-party-plugin

How to restrict some particular products to the selected shipping method?

My Rate Chart is as follows :

[image]

Here, The products of the category ids  4 and 5 are not eligible for **India Post.**

My Requirement is : The selected products have to be restrict for a selected Delivery type.